# print commas after each print statement except the last one

Tags: foreach, tcl

I need some help with my foreach loop logic:

I need to put a comma after each print statement except for the last statement in the loop

ex: `blah,blah2,blahlast`

The following code puts comma even after the last statement.

```
 foreach row $regions {
            set name [lindex $row 0]
            set id [lindex $row 1]
            puts "{'name':'$name', 'val':'$region_id'}"
            puts ","

        }
```

Maybe if i count the number of times its going to loop, I can probably check for an if condition to put comma unlti its the last iteration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to print the comma on all the iterations but the first one (that is, to reverse your logic):

```
set xs {a b c}
set s ""
set need_comma false
foreach x $xs {
  if {$need_comma} {
    append s ,
  } else {
    set need_comma true
  }
  append s $x
}
puts $s
```

would produce

```
a,b,c
```

Note that it seems you're merely looking for the [`join`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/join.htm) command.

Comment: can you see my edit to the question..i dont think this logic will work with my code.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to approach it is to build a list of items to print and join it at the end:

```
set lines {}
foreach row $regions {
    set name [lindex $row 0]
    set region_id [lindex $row 1] ;# changed this from id to region_id, seemed right
    lappend lines "{'name':'$name', 'val':'$region_id'}"
}
puts [join $lines ",\n"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I voted +1 for RHSeeger because that is what I would do. However, it seems you are trying to convert a TCL list to Python's list. If that is the case, you don't even have to worry about suppressing the last comma: Python allows that:

```
>>> li = [1,2,3,]
>>> len(li)
3
```

That means, your current solution works. Don't worry about the last comma.